# Cannot overlay, because ListPlot does not draw same X range despite the same PlotRange

Tags: plotting, graphics, scaling

```
curveData = Import["D:\\Curve.txt", "Table",  "FieldSeparators" -> " "]
lineData = Import["D:\\Line.txt", "Table",  "FieldSeparators" -> " "]
curvePlot = ListPlot[curveData, PlotRange -> {{200, 600}, All},  AxesOrigin -> {200, 0},  Frame -> {True, True, True, False}]
linePlot = ListPlot[lineData, PlotRange -> {{200, 600}, All},  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0]}, AxesOrigin -> {200, 0},  Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, Filling -> Axis,  FillingStyle -> {Thickness[Tiny]}]
Overlay[{curvePlot, linePlot}]
```

I am trying to overlay two plots. However, overlay does not produce aligned plots. The reason seems to be that the plots don't have the same absolute X range, despite the same PlotRange. Could you help to comment the reason ? Many thanks !

[Curve.txt](https://gist.github.com/jiucenglou/635dcab1b1a0a643440648206de5c194#file-curve-txt)

[Lines.txt](https://gist.github.com/jiucenglou/635dcab1b1a0a643440648206de5c194#file-lines-txt)

```
{curveData, lineData} = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/SEg5tThi", "RawJSON"];
```

[image: Cannot overlay]

Comment: Try `Show` instead of `Overlay`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Could you help to suggest more specifically how to use `show` in this circumstance ? Many thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to combine the plots and keep the frame scales that seem intended by the OP.  It would have been easier if `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{curveScale, curveScaleInv}] `` didn't insist that log-spaced major ticks were the way to go.  One can use [`` Charting`ScaledTicks ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Charting+ScaledTicks) in place of `myScaledTicks` in many cases.

```
{curveData, lineData} = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/SEg5tThi", "RawJSON"];

(* creates scaling functions
 *   to scale data to canonical {0,1} interval and back *)
ClearAll[scalingFunctions];
scalingFunctions[data_] :=
  Function /@ ({Rescale[#, #2, #3], Rescale[#, #3, #2]} &[#, MinMax@data, {0, 1}]);
{curveScale, curveScaleInv} = scalingFunctions[curveData[[All, 2]]];
{lineScale, lineScaleInv} = scalingFunctions[lineData[[All, 2]]];

(* creates ticks corresponding to scaling functions *)
ClearAll[myScaledTicks];
myScaledTicks[{sf_, isf_}][min_, max_, n_: {6, 6}] := 
  Module[{major, minor},
   {major, minor} = FindDivisions[isf@{min, max}, n] /. x_Rational :> N[x];
   minor = Complement[Join @@ minor, major];
   major = {
       sf[#], #,
       {0.01, 0.},
       {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}
       } & /@ major;
   minor = {
       sf[#], Spacer[{0, 0}],
       {0.005, 0.},
       {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}
       } & /@ minor;
   Join[major, minor]
   ];
```

Plot of OP's data:

```
Show[
 curvePlot = ListPlot[curveData, PlotRange -> {{200, 600}, All}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {200, 0}, Frame -> True, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {curveScale, curveScaleInv}],
 linePlot = ListPlot[lineData,
   PlotRange -> {{200, 600}, All}, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0]}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {200, 0}, Filling -> Axis, 
   FillingStyle -> {Thickness[Tiny]}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {lineScale, lineScaleInv}],
 FrameTicks -> {
   {myScaledTicks[{curveScale, curveScaleInv}],
    myScaledTicks[{lineScale, lineScaleInv}]},
   {Automatic, Automatic}},
 FrameLabel -> {{"curve (units?)", "line (units?)"}, {"x (units?)", None}}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your knowledgeable help !

Comment: @SOUser You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

```
{curveData, lineData} = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/SEg5tThi", "RawJSON"];


curvePlot = ListPlot[
   curveData
   , PlotRange -> {{200, 600}, All}
   , AxesOrigin -> {200, 0}
   , Frame -> {True, True, True, False}
   ];
linePlot = ListPlot[
   lineData.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 40000}]
   , PlotRange -> {{200, 600}, All}
   , PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0]}
   , AxesOrigin -> {200, 0}
   , Frame -> {False, False, False, True}
   , Filling -> Axis
   , FillingStyle -> {Thickness[Tiny]}
   ];

Show[curvePlot, linePlot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Show[{curvePlot, linePlot}]
```

[image]

As you can see the scaling of your data should be adapted!

Answer (score 3):

If you want a more automated version of @MiachelE2's answer, you can use the `CombinePlots` function of the [`` ForScience` ``](https://github.com/MMA-ForScience/ForScience) paclet (see below for instructions on how to install it) with the setting `"AxesSides" -> "TwoY"` (see the documentation of the paclet for more details and examples):

```
<<ForScience`

{curveData, lineData} = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/SEg5tThi", "RawJSON"];

curvePlot = ListPlot[
  curveData,
  PlotRange -> {{200, 600}, All},
  AxesOrigin -> {200, 0},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"x axis", "curve (units?)"}
  ]
linePlot = ListPlot[
  lineData,
  PlotRange -> {{200, 600}, All},
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0], Red},
  AxesOrigin -> {200, 0},
  Filling -> Axis,
  FillingStyle -> {Thickness[Tiny]},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"x axis", "line (units?)"},
  FrameStyle -> Red
  ]
```

[image]

```
CombinePlots[curvePlot, linePlot, "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]
```

[image]

Note how the `FrameLabel`,`FrameTicks` and `FrameStyle` of the second plot were automatically moved to the right side

**How to install the paclet**

The current version (0.88.45) of the paclet can be installed by running

```
PacletInstall[
  "https://github.com/MMA-ForScience/ForScience/releases/download/v0.88.45/ForScience-0.88.45.paclet"
]
```