# ErrorListPlot (in ver. 12) and double-Y plots

Tags: plotting

Both of my questions concern `ListPlot`, so I hope it is acceptable to ask them both in one post.

1. `ErrorListPlot` seems to have been suspended as of version 12, is there a built-in alternative for creating scatter plots with errorbars?
2. For creating scatter plots with double-Y axes (and shared x-axis), is there a functionality to create a twin-axis (similar to [twinx](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) in Python)? I have tried using `Overlay[{plot1,plot2}]` as a workaround but it creates two slightly shifted plots instead of creating a y-axis opposite side of the original one. Any practical hints for how to create double-Y plots would be very helpful.

Comment: RE: `ErrorListPlot` - this has been superseded by using [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html).

Comment: You are saying it yourself, the documentation clearly indicates *"As of Version 12, ErrorListPlot has been superseded by ListPlot."*. Use  `ListPlot[{Around[1, .1], Around[2, .2], Around[3, .3]}]`

Comment: How is it awkward? It should be fairly trivial to convert any list of points into the `Around` notation.

Comment: In the future please ask one question at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ErrorListPlot

What you achieved before with [`ErrorListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ErrorListPlot.html) now can be achieved with [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)and [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html)

```
data = Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]
ErrorListPlot[data]

ListPlot[
 Apply[
  Around
  , data
  , {1}
  ]
]
```

[image]

From the example in the documentation for [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html)

```
rmdata = DeleteMissing[
   ExoplanetData[
    EntityClass["Exoplanet", All],
    {"MassAround", "RadiusAround"}
    ]
   , 1
   , 1
   ];

ListPlot[
 rmdata
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameLabel -> {"mass (kg)", "radius (m)"}
 , ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}
 , PlotRange -> {{10^25, Automatic}, Automatic}
 , PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}
 , IntervalMarkersStyle -> LightGray
 , ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image]

### double-Y axes

That already has an answers here:

- [Cannot overlay, because ListPlot does not draw same X range despite the same PlotRange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/201265/10397)
- [1 Plot, 2 Scale/Axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis)
- [Plot 2 plots together with different y-axis: in version 10 will not plot entire range](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100406/10397)
- [Overlay vs Show to combine plots?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103073/10397)

Comment: Might be worth linking to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201265/cannot-overlay-because-listplot-does-not-draw-same-x-range-despite-the-same-plo/) as well for an example of how to combine general plots (as far as I can tell, the others are mostly specialized to a specific plot type)

Comment: @user929304 did you read the documentation for `Around` that I linked? Try `{Around[1, 0.1], Around[2, 0.1]}`. If you really need more help **after reading the documentation**, you should ask another question.Read [this](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808)